# Set method waits for another render before populating table while others do not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 5 checkboxes which are used to filter data in a table. I have two functions for filtering using these checkboxes.  One of these functions filters the data while the user is on the page.  The other function filters the data when the page loads.  I have my filters broken down into two steps, the first of which focuses on two checkboxes and their combinations, the second step focuses on the other three check boxes.

The three checkboxes can be called `check1`, `check2` and `check3`.  There are 8 combinations to be checked for here, but only two do not work (combinations 6 & 7).  The check for both combinations works, but the filtered data is not set into the table.

Is there any reason why `setFilteredData` in combination 6 & 7 does not populate the table on render?  If I comment out any on of the `console.log` and allow another render, the filters function as expected.

```
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

const filterData = (dataList) => {
   var data = dataList;

   if (check4 && check5) {
      data = dataList.actions;
   } else if (check4 && !check5) {
      data = dataList.actions?.filter((x) => x.ActionFor !== "Adam");
   } else if (!check4 && check5) {
      data = dataList.actions?.filter((x) => x.ActionFor !== "Eve")
   }

   if (check1 && !check2 && !check3) {
      console.log(1);
      ...
   } else if (check1 && !check2 && check3) {
      console.log(2);
      ...
   } else if (check1 && check2 && !check3) {
      console.log(3);
      ...
   } else if (check1 && check2 && check3) {
      console.log(4);
      ...
   } else if (!check1 && !check2 && check3) {
      console.log(5);
      ...
   } else if (!check1 && check2 && !check3) {
      console.log(6);
      setFilteredData(data?.filter(...));
   } else if (!check1 && check2 && check3) {
      console.log(7);
      setFilteredData(data?.filter(...));
   } else if (!check1 && !check2 && !check3) {
      console.log(8);
      ...
   }
}
```